# 'FullCalendar" can't adjust time lower than 30 minutes

Tags: angular, ionic2, fullcalendar, primeng, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am working on the [Schedule](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/schedule) in PrimeNG

I am facing the issue how to add time to the Schedule. I see that it only can add date to the Schedule and adjust the time more than 30 minutes. It can't adjust the duration time lower than 30 minutes.

I am using Angular 2 technology in my app. Do you have any ideas for my case ? I want to create the Schedule like Microsoft Outlook. It can add the time and date to the Schedule.

I am using this [sample code](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/schedule) from PrimeNG

Comment: Bad tagging, learn the technology you use... Sure you use primefaces?

Comment: I want to ask the same; Do you sure about primefaces?

Comment: Sure ! I am using Primefaces for my application. My app is created by using Angular 2. I want to create the schedule calendar. So, The PrimeNG is best option for me now.

Comment: You can access my link :  https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/schedule and try the demo there. You can see my issue I describe above

Comment: PrimeFaces is a component library for JSF. You're not using it, you're using PrimeNG. Retagged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You linked [the documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/schedule) yourself, it says that the property `slotDuration` allows you to set the desired time slot duration.

Comment: Great ! Thanks ! It works well. I have one more question. How can I add the specified time to the p-schedule ?

Comment: @SonNguyen, I don't know Angular/PrimeNG at all. And I don't understand what time you're trying to add and to what. You better post a separate question and expand on that.